# Exact Phrase Not working properly in mongodb full text search

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, database

I'm currently having some issues with the full text search functionality in MongoDB with or condition. Specifically when trying to match exact phrases with or condition.

Exact Phrase and or condition Not working properly in mongodb full text search

```
{
$text: { $search: "cake \"coffee shop\"" }
}
```

i want result which find all documents containing “cake” or “coffee shop”:

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases).

> If the search string includes phrases, the search performs an AND with any other terms in the search string; e.g. search for "\"twinkle twinkle\" little star" searches for "twinkle twinkle" and ("little" or "star").